# Azure logic app service bus trigger scalability

Tags: azure, scalability, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to read messages from a service bus queue using logic app. I do not find any documentation on how the logic app will scale based on the number of messages in the queue. Any help or pointer very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the answer is...it just does.  Meaning, unless you are using a singleton LogicApp, Azure will spin up as many LogicApp instances as needed.

In other words, yes, **it scales based on demand using any Trigger**, not just Service Bus.

Consequently, there is no built in way to limit the number of instances.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess compared to case of azure functions where documentation mentions presence of a scaler in front to control scale up instances and wait period before running up new instances, there is nothing similar documented for logic app. In between I tested by populating a queue with 40 messages and then creating a logic app that reads from the queue with a 20 sec delay - I observed that 40 instances were created. So I trust "trusting" the inbuilt mechanism whatever that be is the way to go now and perhaps will work safely :)

Comment: @shaswatapal Keep in mind, Azure Functions also work this way to when using a Consumption plan.

Comment: agree - my point was the documentation mentions more details on azure function scalability in consumption plan mode, similar is not available at same detail for logic app :)